# Node app upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

There are manu questions/answer regarding this but my issue not fixed from any solution there so I am writing here .

My node application is working fine on my dev environment but on prod when I request some api which take long time it throw 502 error .

On checking log I got this issue

> 2019/02/22 12:16:57 [error] 2575#0: *2 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   172.31.85.97, server: , request: "GET /api//m2/v1/metrics_report?auth=asdsdffk HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://172.17.0.3:80/api/m2/v1/metrics_report?auth=asdsdffk", host:
>   "", referrer: ""

Comment: Are you using nginx for proxy and expressjs for backend?

Comment: yes I am using same @Ashvin777

Comment: And both are running on the same machine right? Is this logs shared by you generated by express application or this is something you are getting in your api response?

Comment: logs are generated from AWS

Comment: Are you doing some big data operation using that API which takes extra time to respond? also after this happens does your express js stops working or it doesn't crash? Any way you can share express app logs?

Comment: Yes , It comes when i hit api which return big data , but previously It throw 504 , which is for timout now 502 which I am not getting . It is Express Error logging throw AWS @Ashvin777

Answer (score 4):

I think the error from `nginx` is indicating that connection is closed from server. Something must have broken in `express` application during the large data processing which has caused this. You can try to increase the timeouts in nginx to debug this properly -

```
location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 1000s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 1000s;
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was `express` misconfiguration. So, after reading and looking up here and there, I finally come up with the answer. Set the httpServer timeout just like the example below:

```
var httpServer = app.listen(8000, () =>
   console.log('App is listening on port 8000.')
)

httpServer.setTimeout(1000)
```